# How can I use two classes with the same name?

Tags: php

I have installed two packages using Composer (PHP).
One is

```
/Package1/Subfolder/Client
```

the second is named

```
/Package2/Subfolder2/Client
```

When I try to make instances of the two, PHP breaks with "PHP Fatal error: Cannot use package2\Subfolder2\Client as Client because the name is already in use".

Renaming didn't work. Too many files referring to the original.

Comment: It even hints you to use AS and create an alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do:

```
use Package1\Subfolder2\Client as Client1;
use Package2\Subfolder2\Client as Client2;
```

Then you can use it as

```
new Client1;
new Client2;
```

Comment: Or use the fqcn: `$client2 = new Package2\Subfolder2\Client();`